Difference of boundary conditions between elliptic and parabolic PDEs
For elliptic PDEs we know that the boundary condition no matter Dirichlet, Neumann or mixed, needs to be defined over the whole boundary of the given volume $\partial V$. Only then we will get a unique solution of the PDE. However when it comes to parabolic PDEs when we want to solve some of the upper-mentioned BCs in let's say a cylinder, for the sides of this cylinder where $x_4=t=\text{const}$, we only need one of those to have a function $u(x_1,x_2,x_3,t_0)$ that fixes a boundary condition. Now this is pretty intuitively understandable in a physical sense (we let the temperature vary and get whatever we get), but I can't understand quite why we need the whole surface to have defined boundary for elliptic but not for parabolic equations. Is it because this side of the cylinder is characteristic? That is it satisfies:
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^4a_{ij}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}=0\,\ \ ;\ \ \ \hat{a}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Where $F=F(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4=t)$ is the equation of the hyper-surface. If that is correct can you explain why is it the case? Or if it's not why we need one condition less?
